# Git how to set git to prompt fingerprint instead of password?

Tags: git

the first time when I use git clone, git asked about use password or finger print.

I choose password however the git clone failed at password authentication.

How do I reset git so that I can choose to use `fingerprint`? (I have setup ssh key fingerprint in my gitlab). I think fingerprint login method should works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your git remote URL (`git remote -v`, from the root folder of your local repository): if it is HTTPS (https://...), no amount of SSH fingerprint would matter.

And if it is HTTPS, most Git remote hosting services (GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket) requires a [token (PAT)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) as a password, not your actual account password. So make sure to use a token.

If it is SSH, check `git config --local -l` and see if there is any setting ssh / password related.

Answer (score 0):

install git

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
sudo apt install git-lfs
```

configure

```
git config --list

git config --global user.name userA

git config --global user.email userA@email.com
```

remove existing keys

```
cd ~/.ssh/

nano known_hosts  (remove content)
```

generate new key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C newkey
```

install xclip to be able to copy key

```
    sudo apt install xclip
```

copy the key

```
xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

add the content to gitlab user preferences - ssh key new key

test

```
ssh -T git@yourgitlab.com (enter yes, the test should be success Welcome to GitLab, @userA!)
```

Comment: So in the end, were your URL an https one?

Comment: yes the gitlab is on https

Comment: OK. A token is needed then indeed.